# How can I return to a string address and then assign it to a new string?

Tags: c, pointers, string

I have 1 function that I want to return the address of an assigned string to the main function and assign an new string pointer with the same address so that the new string will have the contents of the old string.

For example:

```
 unknown_datatype function()
 {
      char *old = "THE STRING";
      return old;
 }

 int main()
 {
      char *snew = "";
      snew = function();
      return 0;
 }
```

*unknown_datatype means I don't know that to put there...

*How can I approach this without changing anything in the main() method

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking... what are you trying to accomplish, exactly? Also, you might want to avoid using "new"... it isn't a keyword in C, but it is in C++... compile the same code under a C++ compiler and you'll be in big trouble, so you should probably avoid that.

Comment: You can embed keywords in an identifier, so long as the whole identifier isn't a keyword. `snew` is a perfectly acceptable C++ identifier, just like `newtons` or `newAge` would be.

Comment: @Tyler, his original post used "new", not "snew".

Comment: Ah, sorry. There was no "edited X mins ago" notice, so I assumed I was seeing the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you will pass the address of the first element in an array of chars in, as well as the length, and have the function fill it.

```
int fillMyString(char *str, int buffer_size)
{
  if(buffer_size > strlen("test"))
  {
    strncpy(str, "test", buffer_size-1);
    str[buffer_size-1] = '\0';
    return strlen(str);
  }

  return 0;
}


//In some function or main
char buffer[1024];
fillMyString(buffer, 1024);
ASSERT(!strcmp(buffer, "test"));
```

**Edit:** You mentioned that for some reason you need to return a char*.  I would suggest in that case to use `malloc` to allocate the string inside the function, but make sure whenever you call the function you `free` the return value eventually.

Comment: +1 for passing in the buffer... otherwise, you have ambiguous ownership or non-reentrance. Passing in a buffer allows the function to be non-reentrant and makes it clear who is responsible for allocation/deallocation.

Comment: -1 for not passing in the size of the buffer. You are risking buffer overflow!

Comment: It make sense your way and thats the way I been doing it since... But is the assignment I have that doesn't let me change main function so I have to assign it like main says.

Comment: I guess I'll have to break the rules

Comment: @Brian, now that you've edited it, I've given you your +1 back.

Comment: Or...return a pointer to the buffer that you're given, like strcpy() et al do.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use 'strncpy(str, "test", len-1)', make sure of the null termination by doing `buffer[len-1] = '\0';`.  Nominally, you should ensure len > 0 too before doing anything.

Comment: @Jonathan: You're right thanks, just in case the string is >= than the passed in length.  Corrected.

Comment: sizeof("test") == sizeof(char *)

you should have local variables s="test" and l=strlen(s);

Comment: @drawnonward: yes of course, someone modified my answer to put that.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return a `char*`.  Since you are returning a pointer to a string literal, it's probably best to return a `const char*`, since you aren't able to modify the string literal:

```
const char* function()
```

And likewise you would want to assign the return value to a `const char*`:

```
const char* snew = 0;
snew = function();
```

Comment: I get this [Warning]: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Probably `function` is declared below this line. If the C compiler does not have a declaration for a function that you are calling when it encounters the call, it assumes that the function returns `int`. You need to create a prototype for your function that precedes the line where you call `function`.

Answer (score 0):

The unknown data type would have to be `char*` but in this case it would not do what you expect since the variables in `function()` are local variables that will disappear once the function exits and they get popped off the stack. You could use a `malloc()` call inside the function and return a pointer to the new string. Just don't forget to free it when you're done with it.

Comment: String literals have static storage duration, so a pointer to the string literal `"THE STRING"` is valid after the function returns (the lifetime of the string literal is the lifetime of the program).

Comment: It is a fine point of detail that although the pointer to the data in the function is destroyed, the string literal that it pointed at probably still exists, unchanged.  I'm not certain whether the C Standard speaks to that.  Your comment would be 100% valid if the declaration in the function was `char old[] = "THE STRING";`.

Comment: @Jonathan:  When you say "comment," are you referring to Fred's answer or to my comment to the answer?

Comment: @James: well, I was making the same point as you made at the same time you were making your comments.  When I said 'repeat' against my comment to Romain's answer, I was repeating the comment I'd made against Fred's answer - and after I'd submitted, I found you had also made roughly the same comment as me against the same two answers.  So, lots of repetition - by me, and by you.

Comment: @Jonathan:  Ok; sorry, I was just confused :-).

Answer (score 0):

As Brian pointed out, the most idiomatic thing to do in C is to pass a buffer, so you would do:

```
int give_me_a_string(char* buffer, int buffersize)
{
   const char* result = "Hello world!";
   int requiredbufferlen = strlen(result)+1;
   if ( (buffer==0) || (buffersize<requiredbufferlen) ){
       errno = EINVAL;
       return -1;
   }
   strncpy(buffer,"Hello world!",buffersize);
   buffer[buffersize-1]='\0';
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int buffersize = 256;
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(buffersize);
    if ( buffer == 0 ){
       printf("Out of memory!\n");
       return 1;
    }
    if ( give_me_a_string(buffer,buffersize) < 0 ){
       printf("Oh my god, there's an error!\n");
       free(buffer);
       return 1;
    }else{
       printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you absolutely have to not pass in the buffer, then you could write:

```
char* give_me_a_string(void)
{
   const char* str="Hello world!";
   int buffersize = strlen(str)+1;
   char* result=(char*) malloc(buffersize);
   if ( result == 0 ){
       return 0;
   }
   strncpy(result,str,buffersize);
   result[buffersize-1]='\0';
   return result;
}
```

However, if you use the above, then you have to remember to `free()` the result. However, I strongly suggest you use the former approach; when a function return a pointer object, it is not clear who has ownership (i.e. who is responsible to deallocate the string). By requiring the caller to pass in the buffer, you make that ownership explicit (i.e. the caller owns the buffer and must deallocate it himself/herself).

There is one last solution that you can use. If you are returning a constant string, then this is acceptable; however, if you need to compute the string, doing this makes it non-reentrant, and so I would highly advise against doing it. Actually, I would highly advise against this solution even if you were returning a constant string, because then the API cannot adapt to the case where you do need to compute the string. This method is to use a shared global variable that contains the result, so it would be like:

```
// declaration
char* give_me_a_string(void);

// implementation
char* global_string = "Hello world!";
char* give_me_a_string(void)
{
   return global_string;
}
```

This last solution doesn't require any deallocation, because the function, itself, is the owner. If you were doing this with a computed string, it would look like:

```
// declaration
char* give_me_a_string(void);

// implementation
char* global_string = 0;
static void deallocate_global_string()
{
    free(global_string);
    global_string=0;
}

char* give_me_a_string(void)
{
   if ( global_string == 0){
       // allocate global_string
       // ...
       // initialize global_string
       // ...
       // ensure it is eventually freed
       atexit(&deallocate_global_string);
   }
   return global_string;
}
```

As should be obvious, if  you do this it is non-reentrant (it won't work with multiple threads), and so it is a really, really terrible idea. If you get burned, let me just say, I warned you.

Comment: Make sense Like I reply to him but I need to make it work without passing any parameters... (I cannot change the main() method meaning I cannot pass parameters)

Comment: @Y_Y, you will need to change the main function, anyway, to call "free".

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the answer: Since I cannot EDIT the main (MEANING I CANNOT PASS ANY PARAMETER) the following solution is possible:

```
char *function()
{

    char *old;
    old = (char*)malloc(9999);
    strcpy(old,"THE STRING");
    return old;
}

int main()
{
    char *snew = "";
    snew = function();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all who replied.

Comment: @Y_Y, that solution leaks. Now, that may be fine because it is main, but for any other function, that would not be a valid solution.

Comment: True, But for the given project or assignment I know the user will have to limit their input to 3 characters so '9999' is a little too much... I understand where u r coming from but for the given problem, I think that is a fair solution

Comment: Since `function` never returns anything else, it could just return "THE STRING" directly or return a pointer to a static buffer.

Comment: Yeah, if I post the entire code then it'll make sense why this method is the most wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * function()
{
    char *old = "THE STRING";
    return old;
}

int main()
{
     char *snew = "";
     snew = function();
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and example are contradicting each other.

Is this what your looking for ? given below are two simple solutions.

char* func(char *);

int main()

{

```
char *newstring="Hey";

newstring = func(newstring);

printf("New string : %s\n", newstring);
```

}

char* func(char *s)

{

```
printf("Old string : %s\n", s);

s="Hello";

return(s);
```

}

or else the solution given by Y_Y is also fine, assuming your string is created in the function call. Just in case you do not want to use malloc, the solution below works.

char* func();

int main()

{

```
char *newstring="";

newstring = func();

printf("New string : %s\n", newstring);
```

}

char* func()

{

```
char *s="Hello";

printf("Old string : %s\n", s);

return(s);
```

}